# Return default data from second query if the first query returns NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a select query. How can I set the result of my select which select not exist item to 0.

Here's an example table:

```
Name      Purchase
Vahn      TV
Vahn      SmartPhone
Ashe      SmartPhone
Vlad      TV
Vlad      Notebook
Vlad      SmartPhone
```

What i'd like to do, when I select non existing value in the table like this:

```
SELECT Purchase FROM example WHERE Name = 'Balthier'
```

My expected result is :

```
Name       Purchase
Balthier      -
```

and vice versa

```
SELECT Name FROM example WHERE Purchase = 'Drone'
```

My expected result is :

```
Purchase       Name
Drone           -
```

Is it possible in MySQL query only? Or there are better suggestion. Any hel is greatly appreciated. Thank You

nb:

I've tried IFNULL and COALESCE, but still have no luck :(

Comment: the result set is zilch from your query. So yes it is possible (it is going to look real ugly), but what you are doing with ifnull or coalesce requires a row (and columns to use those two against)... so you are out of luck with that

Comment: are you using any programming language like php?

Comment: yes. I'm using PHP (Code Igniter).

Comment: @Drew: What zilch means? and if posibble, can you show me the query. If the query looks ugly, it's ok

Comment: I think 1000111 just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want this?

```
select coalesce(Name, 'Balthier') as Name, coalesce(Purchase, '-') as Purchase
from (select 1) t
left join example a
on a.Name = 'Balthier'
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4604/10)

And for *vice versa*

```
select coalesce(Purchase, 'Drone') as Purchase, coalesce(Name, '-') as Name
from (select 1) t
left join example a
on a.Purchase = 'Drone'
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4604/11)

Comment: This one works too. I test it  in my phpmyadmin and it's working too. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first expected result you may try the following query:\

```
SELECT 
Name,
Purchase 
FROM example 
WHERE Name = 'Balthier'

UNION 

SELECT 
*
FROM 
( SELECT 'Balthier','-' ) AS t
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0;
```

In order to get the second expected result try this:

```
SELECT 
Purchase,
Name 
FROM example 
WHERE Purchase = 'Drone'

UNION 

SELECT 
*
FROM 
( SELECT 'Drone','-' ) AS t
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0;
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH:(using `NOT EXISTS`)**

```
SELECT 
Purchase,
Name 
FROM example 
WHERE Purchase = 'Drone'

UNION 

SELECT 
*
FROM 
( SELECT 'Drone','-' ) AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
        *
        FROM example 
        WHERE Purchase = 'Drone'
)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/187d4/1/0)

Comment: i got error like this:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 12

Comment: My query : SELECT COALESCE(purchase,'-') AS purchase FROM example WHERE name = 'Balthier'.

Comment: your query show error from the line with 'UNION'. but oddly when I separate the query it shows no error

Comment: I've copied the query and table structure to my phpmyadmin. But still throws error. Is it phpmyadmin ?? your query is exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: Please check the **sql fiddle** demo in my answer. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $name='Balthier';
    $query="SELECT Purchase FROM example WHERE Name = '$name'";
    $result=$db->query($query);
    $row=$db->feth_array($result);

 ?>

 <?php if($row==''){?>
     <table border="1">
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>Purchae</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
         <td>-</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<?php }?>
```

If you are using php then you can also show your result like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll save this answer as option B. Still trying to find the answer using the sql query.